# Apresentar consulta do Ajax em outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, query

Bom dia. Estou fazendo uma aplicação web de corridas compartilhadas, tipo "Uber".
Quero que apresente uma consulta ao banco de dados com a lista de motoristas cadastrados pesquisando pelo cpf, mas que quero que mostre nesse carrossel verde.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse código com Ajax, ele executa perfeitamente, até coloquei uma div la embaixo pra testar e funciona perfeitamente.

```
<div id="motorista" style="height: 380px;">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <div class="input-field col s10 ">
        <input placeholder="Busca por CPF" id="cpf" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2 ">
        <button class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" id="buscar"><i class="material-icons">search</i></button>
    </div>

    <script>

        function buscar (cpf){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'componentes/cons_motoca.php',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#cons_motoca").html("Segura as pontas");
                },
                data: {cpf: cpf},
                success: function (msg){    
                    $("#cons_motoca").html(msg);
                }
            })
        }

        $('#buscar').click(function(){
            buscar($("#cpf").val());
        });

    </script>
</div>

// resto de código

</div>

<div id="cons_motoca"></div>
```

Mas preciso que apresente nesse código externo, que é o do carrossel:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true" style="height: 480px;">
<div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
<a class="btn waves-effect white teal-text darken-text-2">Excluir</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item teal white-text" href="#one!">
<h2>Lista de Corridas</h2>
<p class="white-text"><div id="cons_motoca"><?php include("componentes/cons_motoca.php"); ?></div></p>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item teal lighten-1 white-text" href="#two!">
<h2>Lista de Motoristas</h2>
<p class="white-text">Aqui apresentará uma lista dos Motoristas cadastrados</p>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item teal lighten-2 white-text" href="#three!">
<h2>Lista de Passageiros</h2>
<p class="white-text">Aqui apresentará uma lista dos Passageiros cadastrados</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta direito, você já conseguiu montar a consulta mas não consegue alimentar o carousel?

Comment: sim, a consulta já esta montada, perfeita, mas não consigo apresentar no carrossel...

Comment: O código parece correto, o que não está dando certo?

Comment: sim, o código esta correto, mas não sei como apresentar a lista de motoristas no carrossel... sei que deve ser algo bem simples, mas como sou iniciante, não consigo descobrir...

Comment: Quando vc faz a consulta não aparece nada na div?

Comment: Acredito que devo ter que mexer em algo no script do Ajax...

Comment: então, aparece na div que esta na própria página, mas preciso que apresente numa div que esta em outra página

Comment: O que a outra página tem a ver com a página que está chamando o ajax? é uma página filha?

Comment: Se a outra página foi aberta a partir da página do Ajax, é possível fazer isso, mas se não for, não tem como pq elas não tem nenhum vinculo.

Comment: A primeira página é onde tem os campos de consulta de cpf pra buscar o motoristas e o script ajax. A segunda é onde tem o carrossel, que é onde quero que apareça a lista dos motorista.

Comment: Como eu disse, é impossível jogar o resultado de um Ajax em outra página, EXCETO se as duas tiverem um vinculo, ou seja, se uma foi aberta pela outra.